# How to use Update when Rule::Unique is set

Tags: php, laravel

When I add a new client I have to enter name,email and also register_number which has to be unique. Now if I want to edit this user data I get an error that the register number (if i don't change it but i have to have bility to change it also) was already used. How to now disable uniqe for register number when I want to update client iformation.
Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'type' => 'required',
        'register_number' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('clients')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('active',1);
            })->ignore('register_number', when update) 

        ];
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your question not clear plz explain clearly

Comment: make a new request for updating ? :)

Comment: @Hamelraj Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are passing **register_number** column to ignore but its wrong you have to pass **primaryKey** which you are going to update

Example : if your PK is in your client table you have to use like below

```
Rule::unique('clients')->where(function ($query) {
      return $query->where('active',1);
})->ignore('client_id',$client_id)
```

check this [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#Forcing%20A%20Unique%20Rule%20To%20Ignore%20A%20Given%20ID:)

Answer (score 0):

To query I had to add:

```
ignore($this->id)
```

So finally:

```
return [
            'type' => 'required',
            'register_number' => [
                                    'required',
                                    Rule::unique('clients')->where(function ($query) {
                                        return $query->where('active',1);
                                    })->ignore($this->id)

        ];
```